# No wifi interfaces found after logging in as different user

Tags: wifi, wpa

I just configured my Pi ZeroW to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise network. All good. When I log out of the pi account and log back in as another user, the wifi icon is an up/down arrows and when I click it says "No wireless interfaces found", even though I am connected to that same network. If I log out and back in as pi, the SSIDs show up again.

Comment: Update: This also occurs when using a WPA2 Personal SSID, not related to WPA2 Enterprise.

Comment: I thought it might be a groups issue, but my account has the same groups as the default pi account.

Comment: Looks like this is a Raspbian issue. I edited lightdm.conf and made the other user the default user. When I reboot, I see the correct WiFi icon and it shows all of the available SSIDs. When I logout and log back in as the pi user, I have the symptoms described in my original post.

Comment: Please don`t add additional information by comments. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/74289/edit) your question and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

users in netdev group can manage network interfaces. So you should add the user into netdev group to access network config.

You can do this in terminal.

`sudo gpasswd -a [username] netdev`

Comment: This is a very old thread, no longer an issue - and thanks for your belated answer. But to your suggestion, I can only assume that the pi user is in the netdev group and my comments above state that both users were members of the same groups. I'm wondering (too late to check) if the network manager is running for both users.

Comment: @svenyonson Please accept the answer. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it it will not bother us again for years.